# wrong results private array openmp

Tags: c, arrays, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to write a code in C using openmp that runs on my dual core machine and that reads int values from an array and puts the results in an other array but i am getting wrong results. This is my code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int array[10];
int array2[10];
int np,iam;

int main() {
  array[0]=12; // 0
  array[1]=21; // 21
  array[2]=13; // 26
  array[3]=31; // 93
  array[4]=40; // 160
  array[5]=32; // 160
  array[6]=16; // 96
  array[7]=51; // 357
  array[8]=7;  // 56
  array[9]=23; // 207

  int i;
  #pragma omp parallel for private(i,array)
  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    #if defined (_OPENMP)
      np = omp_get_num_threads();
      iam = omp_get_thread_num();
    #endif
    printf("iam %d and i am doing % d\n",iam,i);
    array2[i] = array[i]*i;
  }

  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    printf("%d ",array2[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The non parallel version results are :

```
iam 0 and i am doing  0
iam 0 and i am doing  1
iam 0 and i am doing  2
iam 0 and i am doing  3
iam 0 and i am doing  4
iam 0 and i am doing  5
iam 0 and i am doing  6
iam 0 and i am doing  7
iam 0 and i am doing  8
iam 0 and i am doing  9
0 21 26 93 160 160 96 357 56 207
```

The parallel version results are :

```
iam 0 and i am doing  0
iam 0 and i am doing  1
iam 0 and i am doing  2
iam 0 and i am doing  3
iam 0 and i am doing  4
iam 1 and i am doing  5
iam 1 and i am doing  6
iam 1 and i am doing  7
iam 1 and i am doing  8
iam 1 and i am doing  9
0 -1217558997 1859518440 6 0 -1792801609 1284743096 -364 -1166026656 0
```

Edit 1: I need the array "array" to be private. It have no sence in this case but i am trying to use an array as private to use it later in another case i am working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to be using :

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i) firstprivate(array)
```

firstprivate results in bringing in values from the outside context into the parallel region. Using private clause does not bring the values from the outside context, it just declare a private and not initialised variable so the variable has a random value.